# Who is the boss of Mrs. Smith in Mr. & Mrs. Smith?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-and-mrs-smith

It's been awhile since I saw the film, so I may be remembering the scene wrong. However, early in the film, when "Tank" is called upstairs for a meeting (which he thinks is a promotion, but which actually is his assignment to essentially be bait), there's a quick shot of some guy staring at the computer monitor showing Tank nervously getting in the elevator (to me, it looked like the boss watching his employee coming upstairs - a bit like Stromberg watching his secretary take the plunge in The Spy Who Loved Me).

In my mind, the guy looked a bit like Ice-T, but I couldn't see his credit in IMDB. I always assumed that that one shot was a setup for either later in the film, or for a potential sequel.

Does anyone know who that guy is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keith David http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0202966/

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you for your answer.  One line, mostly link only answers are sometimes not that helpful.  The question says 'couldn't see his credit in IMDB' - can you add some detail to justify why this is the right answer?

Comment: I recognized his voice and jaw line ?

Comment: Welcome to Movies and TV! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It certainly looks like the guy, and he has an ambiguous enough name within the story.

Comment: Wikipedia agrees: He also portrayed "Father" in the movie Mr. and Mrs. Smith. (entry for Keith David)